# VM deployement error in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, vhd

I was getting error while deploying a Windows VM in Azure. This VM image was created from a custom VHD.

Error:

Provisioning failed. OS provisioning for VM did not finish in the allotted time. The VM may still finish provisioning successfully. Also, make sure the image has been properly prepared (generalized).*...

Provisioning State Error Code: ProvisioningState/failed/OSProvisioningTimedOut

Anybody knows why it's failing?

Answer (score 1):

That error can have multiple reasons as you can see in the following documentation

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/error-messages

Besides those reasons, I’ve seen times that you get that error but the VM itself is deployed and works just fine.

Comment: VM status shows running but RDP connection does not work/shows error.

Comment: Try to redeploy it https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/redeploy-to-new-node-windows

Comment: Problem was with the VHD. It was re-created from an running VM.